# treeview grandfather,parent and son names

Tags: vb.net, treeview, names

I have tree view which has grandfather node and inside of this grandfather there is parent and inside this parent there is son node.
How I can get the names of this grandfather , parent and son nodes.
I already did the code to work when the user double clicks on the son node, but still I am unable to get the names for the grandfather, parent and child nodes.
here is my code:

```
 Private Sub TreeView1_NodeMouseDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TreeView1.NodeMouseDoubleClick

        Dim ClickPoint As Point = New Point(e.X, e.Y)
        Dim ClickedChildNode As TreeNode = TreeView1.GetNodeAt(ClickPoint)

        If ClickNode Is Nothing Then

            Exit Sub

        End If

                Dim strGrandFatherName As String
                Dim strParentName As String
                Dim strSonName As String

strGrandFatherName = ?
strParentName = ?
strSonName = ?
```

Thank you
[image]

Comment: The sender would be the Node wouldn't it? Then you could cast it as a TreeNode and inspect its Node.Parent and Node.Parent.Parent?

Comment: If you want the text of all nodes, including the current: `dim nodes = e.Node.FullPath.Split(e.Node.TreeView.PathSeparator.ToCharArray())`. `nodes(0)` is then the root of the current Node, etc.

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, the sender is the `TreeView`, not the `TreeNode`. That said, a reference to the node is provided in `e.Node`, so the code used here to get the node that was clicked is pointless.

Comment: Why choose Grandfather, Parent and Son rather than Grandparent, Parent and Child or Grandfather, Father and Son? It's not a big deal but it seems odd to mix and match gender-neutral and gender-specific terms like that.

Comment: If the user clicks on a node with children then it can have multiple children. For top-level nodes, those children can have multiple children too. Have you considered that, because you haven't given any indication that you have or what you expect to happen in those cases.

Comment: Thanks All of you Guys , thanks Jimi, I took your idea and made modifications to fit my solution it and it worked. I took your idea and mixed it with this solution https://www.w3computing.com/vb2008/vb-treeview-globe-example/